# Is there any way to detect if a makefile variable is poisioned without dying?

Tags: makefile

I'd like in a makefile to find all variables that match a pattern, and print their values.   So I have:

```
$(foreach var,$(filter XX_%,$(.VARIABLES)), \
     $(info $(var)=$($(var))))
```

Nice and simple.   But, in some places people like to poison the variables... i.e.:

```
XX_FOO = $(error XX_FOO is deprecated, please use XX_FOOBAR instead)
```

This causes my above snippet to fail as it tries to expand the variable.   I'm wondering if there's some way to test if a variable is poisoned before expanding it...

Comment: Huh? The `error` is evaluated when the assignment is read, not when referring to the variable.

Comment: oops, wrote post to fast.  should have been `=`.  (also missed a few brackets and `%` in the pattern...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `value` function to avoid interpreting the variable.

BTW, it's helpful if you provide an actual minimal working example: the above has a number of syntax errors.

Try this:

```
errorpat := $$(error%

$(foreach var,$(filter XX_%,$(.VARIABLES)),\
     $(info $(var) =$(if $(filter $(errorpat),$(value $(var))),\
                         $(value $(var)),\
                         $($(var)))))
```

Here `errorpat` is a filter pattern that matches your "poisoned" variables.